# Can not change bios in VMWare

Tags: bios, vmware, vmware-workstation, rom

I have been trying to use a modified BIOS with VMWare, but have been constantly failing.

I have a modified BIOS ROM of the BIOS.440.ROM in the x64 directory of the VMWare Workstation root install directory. I changed the BIOS manufacturer with Phoenix BIOS Editor (biosedit.exe).

I have tried putting it in the Virtual Machine root directory, using a relative path for the 'bios440.filename' property, and putting it in a common directory and using an absolute path to the ROM.

The changes never reflect in msinfo32 on the guest machine which leads me to believe the modified ROM never gets loaded.

The software I am running is VMWare Workstation 17 and the guest operating system is Windows 11 Enterprise N.

Could anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change (update) the BIOS in the HOST machine.

But so far as I know (I use VMware Workstation 17 and all prior), you cannot install BIOS in a Guest VM.

Please see:

[BIOS in VMware guest](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Can-VMWare-use-a-custom-or-alternative-BIOS/td-p/242888)

This is flat-out impossible.

> There's a lot of custom glue in our BIOS that makes it possible for us
> to expose hardware in a way that will allow an OS like Windows to
> boot. Even replacing it with another "paravirtualized" BIOS, for
> example by writing a new EFI BIOS for our virtual hardware, is a
> tremendous amount of work. Trying to run some random BIOS ROM you have
> that targets a specific set of physical hardware is never going to
> work.

**Follow Up:**

If you have a Windows 11 Production machine (I have) and VMware V17 (I have), then you can set up a Guest Machine for UEFI and Secure Boot. But that does not add a BIOS file to the VMware Guest Installation folder.

[image: VMware UEFI Setup]

Comment: Where did you find VMware BIOS that is not host BIOS (which you can update) but for Guests?

Comment: This is not related to my question. I am using the official VMWare BIOS with some cosmetic changes applied via biosedit.exe. The person in the post you linked seems to be receiving an actual error message. My bios440.filename property is refusing to work. I even tried replacing it with gibberish and still received no errors. My question is how to get VMWare to even attempt to load the custom ROM.

Comment: As I said in my question, the BIOS.440.ROM in the x64 directory of the VMWare Workstation root install directory. That is the one used by the VMs.

Comment: The only article I can find for that is VMware ESXi  (but not Workstation). ......  https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/ESXi-4-1-0-582267-using-bios-440-rom-and-running-OS-2012-error/td-p/2182327

Comment: The article you linked in your answer is about Workstation as you can see by its category. The person received an error, meaning Workstation actually attempted to load the ROM.

Comment: In the text:    .....  ESXi 4.1.0,582267; using bios.440.rom and running OS-2012

Comment: Not the comment, the [one](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Can-VMWare-use-a-custom-or-alternative-BIOS/td-p/242888) you linked in the answer. In the text: "...I am using VMware Workstation v6.0.0 Build - 45731."

Comment: So far as I can determine you need ESX to do what you want. The article in my answer is for Workstation and it says you cannot put BIOS in a Workstation guest

Comment: But it also says they got an error message, I never got that far. This [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDft-f-dbJ4) also showcases it working on Workstation.

Comment: The video uses the same settings I showed in my follow up addition to the answer

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up! I would just like to leave this [post](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Changing-UEFI-rom-or-Shell-efi-on-a-VM-by-VM-basis-in/m-p/2309909#M138496) for anyone coming here in the future and wanting to change the UEFI ROM.